# If $K$ is an algebraic semantics for a deductive system $S$, what is the signature of the algebras in $K$ and what is $\models_K$?

Tags: logic

A deductive system $S$ my be *algebraizable* over a language $L$ if there's an a class of algebras $K$ satisfying some conditions.

**I'd like a better sense of what the class $K$ looks like before moving on to the conditions placed on it. What is the signature of the individual algebras that make up $K$ and what exactly is the relation $\models_K$?**

---

I'm going to give a language $L$ a little bit more structure than it is given in BP and say that a language is a set of well-formed formulas and a family of sets of connectives indexed by arity.

A deductive system is defined by Blok and Pigozzi in *Algebraizable Logics* on page 5 as a pair $(L, \vdash_S)$ where $\vdash_S$ is a consequence relation. A consequence relation must satisfy some axioms to be a consequence relation, which I am omitting for brevity.

With that out of the way, on page 14 as well as in the abstract, Blok and Pigozzi describe what exactly an algebraic semantics is, paraphrased below.

Let $S$ be a deductive system. Let $K$ be a class of algebras. $K$ is an algebraic semantics for $S$ if and only if $\vdash_S$ can be interpreted in $\models_K$.

At this point, I'm having a lot of trouble following the text. I'd like to nail down what $\models_K$ and the class $K$ itself are before moving on to understanding the interpretability condition.

- What is $\models_K$ exactly? The text suggests that it is an equivalence relation, but I'm not sure whether it is an equivalence relation *within* individual alegbras or an equivalence relation between algebras in my class.
- I'm assuming that a class of algebras means a class of algebraic structures. I'm not sure what the signature is for these structures, but I'm assuming it's the connectives in $L$ with their respective arities.

---

For completeness, here is the definition of *algebraizability*. $K$ is the class of algebras that witnesses the algebraizability of $S$. This definition appears on page 14 in BP. In addition, $\text{Fm}$ refers to the set of well-formed formulas.

> $K$ is called an algebraic semantics for $S$ if $\vdash_S$ can be
> interpreted in $\models_K$ in the following sense: there exist a
> finite system $\delta_i(p) \approx \epsilon_i(p)$, for $i<n$, of
> equations with a single variable $p$ such that, for all $\Gamma \cup \{ \varphi \} \subset \text{Fm}$ and each $j < n$
>
> $$ \Gamma \vdash_S \varphi \iff \{ \delta_i[\psi/p] \approx \epsilon_i[\psi/p] : i < n , \psi \in \Gamma \} \models_K \delta_j[\varphi/p] \approx \epsilon_j[\varphi/p] \tag{2.1i}$$

Comment: I don't have the book. Your last quotation doesn't look right to me: what does $\Gamma \cup > \{\phi\}$ mean? What does $\delta[\psi/p]$ mean if $p$ is a variable and $\psi$ is an equation or a formula? Should $\vdash_K$ read $\vdash_S$ on the first line of the quotation?

Comment: `>` was a mistake introduced by block-quoting. I caught a few but not all of them. As far as I can tell BP does not define the capture-avoiding substitution notation explicitly, but $p, q, r$ are used as syntactic metavariables, so I think what you said is correct. Also yes, I meant to write $\vdash_S$.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, the notation $\delta[\psi/p]$ still doesn't make sense to me in this context if $\psi$ is a formula. Do the authors not give any description of that notation?

Comment: I have checked through page 20. I haven't found a definition yet, but the following does appear on page 14, which suggests that it is a capture avoiding substitution. QUOTE: Related abbrevations ... such as $\Gamma \models_K \delta(\varphi) \approx \epsilon(\varphi)$ in place of $ \Gamma \models_K \delta_i[\varphi/p] \approx \epsilon_i[\varphi/p] $ for all $i<n$ will also be used.

Comment: I checked every page (the book is quite short) and there isn't an explicit definition for the notation. Although the usage ( $\vartheta[\lambda[\star \xi'/p']/p ]$ ) does appear in an appendix, which really suggests substitution to me. The book is about algebras that are related to the semantics of various propositional calculi (like classical, intuitionistic, and relevant).

Comment: I think I understand it now. You are right about the signatures. The basic idea is that $\Gamma \models_K \psi$, means that $\psi$ holds in very algebra in the class $K$ which satisfies all the formulas in $\Gamma$. It makes sense to substitute formulas in $L$ into terms over $L$, because under the algebraic semantics, the elements of the algebras correspond to truth values in the deductive system. If you need more help, let me know and I'll try to write a more detailed answer.

Comment: So does that mean that the the different algebras in $K$ don't interact at all and $\models_K$ inspects whether a given formula is "true" in a given algebra? Oh, that makes sense I guess. On page ten $p \approx q$ is defined as the second-order formula $\forall P (P(p) \leftrightarrow P(q))$, so it looks like $\approx$ can be true or false in a given algebra even if we don't "designate" some of its elements as chosen. I still don't understand the finiteness condition in the quoted definition, but the definition as a whole is starting to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) In the context of abstract algebraic logic, usually, $\vDash_K$ is the consequence relation defined as follows: Let $\Gamma= \{\epsilon_i\approx\delta_i  \}$ be a set of equation in some signature $\tau$ and let $\epsilon\approx\delta$ be some $\tau$-equation, then $\Gamma\vDash_K \epsilon\approx \delta$ if, for all $H\in K$ and for all homomorphisms $h:\mathcal{F}_{\tau}\to H$ from the $\tau$-term algebra to $H$, we have that $h(\epsilon_i)=h(\delta_i)$ for all $i\in I$ entails $h(\epsilon)=h(\delta).$

(2) Also, you are right about the signature. The signature of a class of algebraic structures which are the equivalent algebraic semantics of some logic $L$ consists of a purely functional vocabulary, which are the operations of the language. For example, if the logic contains $\{0,\land,\lor \}$, then this will be the signature of the corresponsing class of algebras.

(3) Notice that in this context it is incorrect to write $\vDash_K \phi$: what we evaluate in algebraic semantics are equations, not formulas. The reason of this sloppy way of writing, for example in intuitionistic logic under Heyting semantics, is that $\vDash_K \phi$ is taken to mean $\vDash_K \phi\approx 1$ -- i.e. we have some designated value, as you said in the comments.

(4) Finally, I should also mention that the theory of algebraizable logics has quite developed  since the time when *Algebraizable Logic* was first published. For example, I do not think nowadays the set of equations in the definition of algebraisability is taken to be finite, but usually a second map, going from equations to formulas is introduced. I would reccomend having a look at the more recent book *Abstract Algebraic Logic: An Introductory Textbook* by Josep Maria Font.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. Thank you. Can we take BP's presentation and demote the finiteness condition to a theorem? Let's call $L^\approx$ the language of equivalences in $L$, so $\varphi \in L^\approx$ if and only if it is of the form $\psi \approx \psi'$ where $\psi, \psi'$ are in $L$. If $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas in $L^\approx$, is it true that $\Gamma \models \varphi$ implies that there exists a finite $\Gamma_0$ such that $\Gamma_0 \models \varphi$? (Also, how standard/nonstandard is taking our equations and repackaging them as a different language from our original $L$?)

Comment: This Theorem does not always hold: we could have logics which are not finitary, meaning exactly that they do not satisfy the claim you wrote. A study of infinitary universal of Horn theories without equality that applies in turn to infinitary propositional logics is given e.g. in [this (pretty cool) paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/some-characterization-theorems-for-infinitary-universal-horn-logic-without-equality/5933AA4818B43D9B8B5D2EB186A43DCD).

Comment: Also notice that we are not changing language: $\phi,\psi$ are propositional formulas in logic $L$ under signature $\tau$ if and only if they are $\tau$-terms and $\phi\approx\psi$ is a $\tau$-equation. We are not changing language, but rather shifting between propositional and first-order perspective.

Comment: Also, I should say that the definition of algebraizable logic I am most accustomed to is the following: A logic $\vdash$ is algebraizable if there are a quasivariety $K$, a set of equations $\tau(x)$ and a set of formulas $\Delta(x,y)$ such that: (alg1)
   $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ iff $\tau[\Gamma]\vDash^c_{K} \tau(\phi) $, (alg2)  $\Delta[\Theta] \vdash \Delta(\eta,\delta) $ iff $\Theta\vDash^c_{K} \eta\approx\delta$, (alg3)  $\phi \dashv\vdash \Delta[\tau(\phi)]$  and (alg4) $\eta \approx \delta  \equiv_{K}  \tau[ \Delta(\eta,\delta)]$.

Comment: From my limited perspective, it looks a little like a shift in language (where we demote logical symbols in $L$ to non-logical function symbols in $L^\approx$ and we have one predicate $\approx$, so $L^\approx$ looks like a term algebra (is that what the "syntactic algebra" of $L$ is called?) but also has a predicate $\approx$). Also, I have a question about what $\approx$ is. Is it just the "finest congruence available" given the term algebra associated with $L$.

Comment: Okay, I guess you can have this perspective on logical symbols becoming non-logical, though notice that we do not have such difference in propositional logic. However, what is important is that $\approx$ is not a predicate but the equality symbol in the syntax: we use this symbol just to distinguish it from the semantic identity. I think this is standard in universal algebra.

Comment: Also notice the symbol $\vDash_K^c$ in my comment above should just be $\vDash_K$.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I didn't quite get how $\approx$ and $=$ differ, so I asked a follow up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4174222/what-is-the-difference-between-and-approx-in-universal-algebra).