# What is the difference between $=$ and $\approx$ in universal algebra?

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

I'm trying to understand [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172172/if-k-is-an-algebraic-semantics-for-a-deductive-system-s-what-is-the-signatu/4174189?noredirect=1#comment8648136_4174189) on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4174189) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4172172) I asked two days ago.

Specifically, I'm trying to understand the difference between the symbol $=$ and the symbol $\approx$ in a universal algebra setting.

The book I'm using *Algebraizable Logics* defines $\approx$ using a second-order formula $p \approx q \;\;\text{iff}\;\; \forall P \mathop. P(p) \leftrightarrow P(q)$, but I'm not sure whether $P$ is supposed to range over all definable predicates or what.

I'm coming at this specifically from the direction of trying to understand algebraic semantics for nonclassical propositional logics. I have a vague intuition that the elements in the algebras in my variety are supposed to be "similar" to truth values at one end of the spectrum and the full syntax of the propositional logic on the other, so we end up with some kind of lattice of structures with these two as "end points". I think.

---

My understanding of universal algebra is extremely limited and I mostly think of it as model theory without predicate symbols.

First-order logic with equality has a single distinguished logical predicate $=$. The very short introductory entries on [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniversalAlgebra.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) do not mention multiple logical predicates.

Comment: Usually, the formula above is the [Second-Order definition of identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-indiscernible/#Form)

Comment: Maybe the difference is that between the binary predicate symbol (part of the language) and the binary relation used to interpret it (part of the "world").

Comment: See formula (1) page 13: $\xi ≈ \eta \in \Gamma$ is a formula while $\xi^A(a) = \eta^A(a)$ is the equality between objects of the algebra $A$

Comment: Oh I see. Is the idea that $=$ is analogous to $\models$ and $\approx$ is analogous to $\vdash$? In other settings, I've seen $\models$ treated as an extension of the metalanguage (natural language). I think this distinction is there so we can conveniently talk about theorems like $\models \mathop\subset \vdash$ and $\vdash \mathop\subset \models$.

Comment: I don't know the text you are studying. It sounds somewhat unconventional. There are some other good texts on universal algebra available on-line, e.g., http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf. Perhaps you could check them out.

Comment: @RobArthan, thanks for the link to the book. On page 16 (pdf numbering), it answers my question. QUOTE: The symbol $=$ is used to express the fact that both sides name the same object, whereas $\approx$ is used to build equations which may or may not be true of particular elements. END QUOTE.  This seems parallel to the distinction between $\models$ and $\vdash$ in other settings to me.